# applying function to list of dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, apply

beginner python question here that I've had struggles getting answered from related stack questions.

I've got a list

`dfList = df0,df1,df2,...,df7`

I've got a function that I've defined and takes a dataframe as its argument.  I'm not sure the function itself matters, but to be safe it is basically

```
def rateCalc (outcomeDataFrame):
    rateList = list()
    upperRateList = list()
    lowerRateList = list()
    for i in range(len(outcomeDataFrame)):
        lowlevel, highlevel = proportion_confint(count=outcomeDataFrame.iloc[i,4], nobs=outcomeDataFrame.iloc[i,3])
        lowerRateList.append(lowlevel)
        rateList.append(outcomeDataFrame.iloc[i,4]/outcomeDataFrame.iloc[i,3])
        upperRateList.append(highlevel)

    outcomeDataFrame = outcomeDataFrame.assign(lowerRate=lowerRateList)
    outcomeDataFrame = outcomeDataFrame.assign(midrate=rateList)
    outcomeDataFrame = outcomeDataFrame.assign(upperRate=upperRateList)

    return outcomeDataFrame
```

What I'm trying to do is append a the observed success ratio of two numbers as well as their 95% confidence interval.  Goes fine when working with any individual df.

What I want to accomplish is turn each item of dfList into a version of itself with those lowerRate, midRate, and higherRate values appended as new columns.

When I try to apply across each dataframe with

```
for i in range(len(dfList):
   rateCalc(dfList[i])
```

though, it seems to *only* execute for df0.  I can't make any sense of that; a full error I'd assume I had some basic flaw in the code, but it seems to work for df0 and then not iterate to df1 and beyond.

I also thought there may be an issue of "df1 != dfList[1]" in some backend sense (that running the function on the item in a list dfList[1] would not have any affect on the original item df1) but, again, the fact it *seems* to work with df0 would imply that's not the issue.

I also tried throwing some mud at the wall with the "map" function but am not sure I understand how to use that in this context (or any other for that matter ha)

Thanks all

Comment: `df` doesn't exist in your example. Perhaps you want `for df in dfList: rateCalc(df)`.

Comment: @tdelaney thank you, I edited to I corrected that error -- I meant for the for loop to be running off dfList[i] as in dfList[0] = df0, dfList[1] = df[1] and so on.

Comment: It should work. You may need to post a working example for us to spot any bugs. You could add `print(i, id(dfList[i]))` to make sure that list is setup properly.

Comment: Is the `proportion_confint` function complicated? Can you post an example?

Comment: perhaps `for i in range(len(dfList)): dfList[i] = rateCalc(dfList[i])` is what you want. That doesn't explain only processing df0, but it does explain why none of them update.

Comment: @marcio sczepanski that was indeed, at least basically, the issue.

i had some sloppy global vs local variables going on.  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because the assing function returns another Data Frame which only exists inside the function scope, here is an example

```
import pandas as pd
df_0 = pd.DataFrame(data = [{'column':'a'}])
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [{'column':'c'}])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [{'column':'d'}])
df_altos = df_0,df_1,df_2

def mod_df(df):
    test = list()
    test.append('d')
    #print('id before setting another column '+str(id(df)))
    #df['b'] = test
    print('id before assinging '+str(id(df)))
    df = df.assign(lowerRate = test)
    print('id after  assinging '+str(id(df)))
    return df

for i in range(len(df_altos)):
    mod_df(df_altos[i])
```

The returning id of each dataframe is the following

```
id before assinging 1833832455136
id after  assinging 1833832523568
id before assinging 1833832456144
id after  assinging 1833832525776
id before assinging 1833832454416
id after  assinging 1833832521888
```

As you can see, the id changes.
You could try another atribution method, as the following

```
def mod_df(df):
    test = list()
    test.append('d')
    print('id before setting another column '+str(id(df)))
    df['b'] = test
    print('id after assinging '+str(id(df)))
    return df
```

which outputs

```
id before setting another column 1833831955520
id after assinging 1833831955520
id before setting another column 1833791973888
id after assinging 1833791973888
id before setting another column 1833791973264
id after assinging 1833791973264
```

Now the ids are the same and the new column exists on all the dataframes.
How the first dataframe of you code was working i dont know.